# Using If statement, to get one String, to pass into API call

Tags: ios, api, if-statement

**I need to pass a `string` variable into an `API` call, but I'm having a hard time getting the `string` from  an `if` statement.**

Below is what I've tried so far, but I get a warning that "`usersID` is an unused variable" inside each of the `if` statements...

Which makes sense, and is the main problem I'm trying to solve for (i.e. run thru an `if` statement to get one `string` to use after evaluation).

*Thanks for the help, will post any extra code as needed!*

**ViewController.h**

```
  @property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *usersID;

  // Get leaf and theme from Saved defaults
  NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
  NSString *leafAbbreviation = [defaults objectForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"leafAbbreviation"]];
  NSString *themeID = [defaults objectForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"themeId"]];

  // Get ID User number based on Leaf and Theme
  if ([leafAbbreviation isEqualToString: @"new"] && [themeID isEqualToString: @"2"]) {
  NSString *usersID = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"728"];
  }
  else if ([leafAbbreviation isEqualToString: @"new"] && [themeID isEqualToString: @"3"]) {
    NSString *usersID = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"275"];
  }
  else {
  NSString *usersID = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"486"];

  // API
    NSString *path = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"v1/%@/media/?client_id=xxx", usersID];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must have to declare your variable before if statments, use below insetead:

```
// Get ID User number based on Leaf and Theme
NSString *usersID = [NSString stringWithFormat:@""];
if ([leafAbbreviation isEqualToString: @"new"] && [themeID isEqualToString: @"2"]) {
    usersID = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"728"];
}
else if ([leafAbbreviation isEqualToString: @"new"] && [themeID isEqualToString: @"3"]) {
    usersID = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"275"];
}
else {
    usersID = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"486"];
}
```

This will fix your concern.

Comment: Got it, and just leave it blank inside the `@""` for `NSString *usersID = [NSString stringWithFormat:@""];`?

Comment: `[NSString stringWithFormat:@""]` is pointless as the format contains nothing (likewise if the format string contains no format parameters and only plain text). Just use `@""` directly, or `nil` if an empty string has no meaning.

Comment: @Wain, thanks for the info! So just use NSString *usersID = @ " " and then once the if statements run they will fill in the variable usersID?